# How to deserializing JSON using JSON.NET (Getting null results)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am fairly new to C# / JSON and am working on a pet project to show summoner/game information from league of legends.

I am trying to get the summoner id for the requested summoner name.

Here is the JSON returned:

```
{"twopeas": {
   "id": 42111241,
   "name": "Twopeas",
   "profileIconId": 549,
   "revisionDate": 1404482602000,
   "summonerLevel": 30
}}
```

Here is my summoner class:

```
public class Summoner
        {

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
            public string ID { get; set; }

        }
```

Here is the rest:

```
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    var summonerInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Summoner>(result);

    MessageBox.Show(summonerInfo.ID);
```

`summonerInfo.ID` is null and I don't know why.

I'm sure there is something glaringly obvious that I am missing, but I'm at a loss I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Add a class Twopeas and inside it add a property twopeas it is type is a Summoner

Comment: Check out MY OWN answer for this post **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142325/getting-json-object-from-mvc-controller** I use MVC to help with this process. You will see how I call C# with AJAX, C# grabs the JSON, then I pass it back to Javascript to parse it. If you are newer to Javascript/AJAX I'd also recommend that you check out my **[Beginners introduction to Riot API and JSON, using Javascript and Ajax](https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/riot-games-api/show/kvll5V8r)** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ID` is null because your JSON doesn't match the class you're deserializing into.  In the JSON, the `id` property is not at the top level: it is contained within an object which is the value of a top-level property called `twopeas` (presumably representing the summoner name).  Since this property name can vary depending on your query, you should deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, Summoner>` like this:

```
var summoners = 
           JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Summoner>>(result);

MessageBox.Show(summoners.Values.First().ID);
```

Comment: This worked! Now I just need to figure out why...